# How do you reload environment file in a docker swarm service?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I need to change an environment variable in my deployment (nothing else has changed). When I update my environment variables (just using export) and use `docker stack deploy`, the container environment is not updated. How do I make sure environment variables are updated in the container?

Comment: docker stack deploy should pickup any changes to the compose file and redeploy effected services. if not, you can force a service to redeploy with `docker service update --force`

Comment: Or use `docker service update --env-add ...` to add environment variables on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently using `docker stack deploy` should work to update the environment. My error was not having the environment variable defined in the `docker-compose.yml` file.